# Pass parameter to Joomla.submitbutton(task)

Tags: joomla-3.x

I've my custom task = request.state

in my controller, I've code like

```
public function state($param)
{
     //Do my task
}
```

My question is how do I pass $param to

```
Joomla.submitbutton(request.state)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you override Joomla.submitbutton in your view's php file, set a hidden fields value to the request parameter you wish to send, then finally submit the form.

So say your admin view's template has a field

```
<input type="hidden" id="myinfo" value="" >
```

Then you would add some JavaScript to the view's template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Joomla.submitbutton = function(task) {
    jQuery('#myInfo').val('my custom value');
    Joomla.submitform(task, jQuery('#adminForm'));
}
</script>
```

Then your request's $_POST array will have

```
[myInfo] => 'my custom value'
```

Answer (score 2):

@Rob - Thank you very much for your help. However, your method did not work for me. Here's how I made it work:

In my view layout file (default.php):

I added one hidden state field with blank code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="state" value="" />
```

In my JS file I added following code:

```
$('#cancel-request').click(function () {
if (confirm("Are you sure?"))
            {
                $("input[name='state']").val('cancel');
                Joomla.submitbutton('request.state');
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
}
```

In my controller, I added following code:

```
public function state()
{
     $state = $this->input->post->get('state', '');
     // based on $state I made my code.
}
```